# Upload file to Woocommerce Order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add File Upload for checkout process. Here is my code:

Add input after order notes

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'upload_file_checkout' );
function upload_file_checkout() { 
    ?>
    
    <p class="form-row" id="image" data-priority="">
        <label for="image" class="">Image (JPG, PNG, PDF)</label>
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type='file' name='image' accept='image/*,.pdf' multiple='false'>
        </span>
    </p>
    
   <?php
}
```

Next, update order meta

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'checkout_file_update_order_meta' );
function checkout_file_update_order_meta($order_id) {    
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['image'] ) ) {
        
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
        
        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', $order_id );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_image', $attachment_id );

    }
    
}
```

And show the result in admin page

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'show_new_checkout_field_order', 10, 1 );
   
function show_new_checkout_field_order( $order ) {    
   $order_id = $order->get_id();
   echo '<p><strong>Image:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_image', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

But this is not work. How can I fix it?

This is how I see this meta in DB after place an order

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify which part isn't working?  Is it NOT uploading the file or is it not adding the post_meta?  Or is something else going wrong?

Comment: I get an error sending the file

Comment: See if you can locate exactly what the error is - everything seems to be working and it's attempting to add the file but at some point WordPress is objecting and throwing an error.